Как подключить alias к основному домену в рамках GGoogle Cloud Platform
Всем привет!
В рамках GCP поднят сайт со статическим IP. К нему успешно подключен основной домен. Для этого в GCP в Network Services в Cloud DNS создавалась зона. А в регистраторе GoDaddy прописывались гугловские DNS-сервера.

Вопрос: каким образом подключить Alias к основному домену? Нужно ли для этого создавать новую зону?
